# Remove specific characters from string in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to remove  specific characters from a certain string data.

This is my situation.
The chatroomId is generated from the sum of two uids.
For example:

```
(UID1)Lp6D46RdTRWBv5HBJIxJ3TL1hsa2 + (UID2)06drs59V3Ye2Abg2GfJLGZN8B7r2 →(chatroomID)Lp6D46RdTRWBv5HBJIxJ3TL1hsa206drs59V3Ye2Abg2GfJLGZN8B7r2
```

I want to subtract UID1 from chatroomID again.
So, my expectation is

```
(UID2)06drs59V3Ye2Abg2GfJLGZN8B7r2
```

Comment: Couldn't use substring to skip UID1 in the chatroom string https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/String/substring.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use substring to get the desired characters

```
String UID1 = "Lp6D46RdTRWBv5HBJIxJ3TL1hsa2";
String UID2 =  "06drs59V3Ye2Abg2GfJLGZN8B7r2";
String chartoomID = UID1 + UID2;
String newString = chartoomID.substring(UID1.length); #skip UID1

print(UID1); // "Lp6D46RdTRWBv5HBJIxJ3TL1hsa2"
print(UID2); // "06drs59V3Ye2Abg2GfJLGZN8B7r2"
print(chartoomID); // "Lp6D46RdTRWBv5HBJIxJ3TL1hsa206drs59V3Ye2Abg2GfJLGZN8B7r2"
print(newString); // "06drs59V3Ye2Abg2GfJLGZN8B7r2"
```